# Git commit returns error docker/error response from deamon on windows

Tags: git, docker, git-commit

I am running docker for my Laravel application (BE). I have made a simple update on readmeme.md file and tried to commit & push this file to git.

When I try to commit it this is what I get.

`> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/var/www/api' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path. See 'docker run --help'.`

Specs:

- Git: git version 2.38.0.windows.1
- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
- My backend is Laravel

Comment: Someone said I should look into `grumPhp` ( ./.git/hooks/)?  But I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Why is committing triggering/executing Docker? Do you have any hooks set up?

Comment: I did not set up any specific hooks. Everything should be out of the box. If I can somehow "re-install" git or set it back to default I could do that.

Comment: Hooks are (usually?) repository-specific. Check `.git/hooks` if it contains any references to docker or if any of the hook scripts are executable

Comment: Indeed file `commit-msg` does contain this piece of code.

`# Run GrumPHP
(cd "./" && printf "%s\n" "${DIFF}" | 'docker' 'run' '--rm' '-t' '-v' '$(pwd):/var/www' '-w' '/var/www/api' 'my_container_name' 'vendor/bin/grumphp' 'git:commit-msg' "--git-user='$GIT_USER'" "--git-email='$GIT_EMAIL'" "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE")`

Should I remove everything after pipe? How should default commit script look like?

Comment: Then you have set up a Git hook. You can either skip it during commit or you can remove the hook. But I assume it is there for a reason, so you must find out why you put it there in the first place

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I removed / edited this line and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message comes from a Git hook. Check the `.git/hooks` directory if you have set up any Git hooks that invoke Docker. Then find out, why you have them set up and if you need them (e.g. to contribute to a project while adhering to their coding guidelines).

If you don't need them, mark the file as non-executable or delete it. To ignore it for a single commit, pass `--no-verify` to `git commit`.